# Javascript checking for NaN/null?

Tags: javascript

I tried with `isNaN()` and `tmp === null`, but neither works.

```
tmp = $("#n").html();
if(tmp === undefined || tmp === null){
    tmp = 1;
}
tmp = parseInt(tmp);
console.log("tmp: " + tmp);
```

The console logs `tmp: NaN`

I'm trying to give tmp a value if it's empty. The above is taken from another stackoverflow post, but I do not see why it's not working for me.

Comment: NaN mean that tmp can't be parsed as Int, like `"abc"` ...

Answer (score 6):

I think you can just use `tmp = $("#n").html() || 1;`, as the value may be an empty string.

All values including `undefined`, `null`, `''` are so-called `falsy` values. The operator `||` will evaluate it to be `false`, hence goes to the second parameter and returns the default value `1`.

Comment: That worked! And a very smart solution I might add :) Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried this?

```
tmp = $("#n").html();
if(!tmp){
    tmp = 1;
}
tmp = parseInt(tmp);
console.log("tmp: " + tmp);
```

Comment: that's not ok : `if(!tmp)` makes `tmp = 1` if `tmp = 0`

Comment: @Lulylulu if tmp is `"0"` it's ok, `"0"` is not falsy

Comment: @Hacketo He means `0` number is falsy.

Comment: @DmitriPavlutin it can't be `0` as number, tmp is a string

Comment: @Hacketo you're right it is always a string, but it's bad practice.

Comment: @Lulylulu agree if you don't know all values that can be hold by `tmp`

Comment: I just left this suggestion as there is a `parseInt(tmp)` at the nearly end